# Linestring table (of MultiLinestrings) ST_Intersection

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linestring, st-intersects, geoalchemy-2

I'm moving from GeoPandas to PostGIS and GeoAlchemy.

I've a table full of multilinestring geometries (timezones from NaturalEarth.com) and I've a linestring which represents what will be the route of an aircraft. I would like to get the intersected timezones AND the position of intersections.

So far I have the intersected timezones using

```
class TimeZoneLine(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'TimeZone (LineGridExp)'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

lineGeom = func.ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-14 44, 6 44)',4326)

query = session.query(TimeZoneLine).filter(func.ST_Intersects(TimeZoneLine.geom, lineGeom))

for row in query:
    print (row.zone)
```

which prints

```
<__main__.TimeZoneLine object at 0x107656dd8>
<__main__.TimeZoneLine object at 0x107656e48>
<__main__.TimeZoneLine object at 0x107656f98>
<__main__.TimeZoneLine object at 0x107683128>
<__main__.TimeZoneLine object at 0x107683278>
<__main__.TimeZoneLine object at 0x1076833c8>
```

which are the timezones intersected. My question is, how to get the Intersection points.

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271824/st-intersection-intersection-of-all-geometries-in-a-table) seems to have some thing similar but the below is closest I've come:

```
query =  session.query(select([column('zone'),column('id'), column('iso_8601'),column( 'map_color6'), func.ST_intersection(lineGeom, TimeZoneLine.geom)]).select_from(TimeZoneLine).where(func.ST_Intersects(lineGeom, TimeZoneLine.geom)))
```

but this returns

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the intersecting point with ST_Intersection.
But that only work on the geometry type. So you will have to project your data. But since you are working over large areas that might be a problem.

But I think transforming to webmercator should work in this case.
Try transforming both time lines and aircraft routes (on the fly) to webmercator, use ST_Intersection and transform the result back.